# Using for each with a worksheet reference

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

If `ws` below has both the range object and cell property:

```
dim ws as worksheet 
set ws = sheets("sheet_1")

x = ws.range("A1")
x = ws.cells(1,1)
```

Why doesn't this work:

```
dim cel as range
dim rng as range

set rng = 'some range

for each cel in rng
   ws.cel.value = "foo"
next
```

I want to ensure the right `sheet` is being referenced, and it seems logical to use `ws` as part of the `cel` reference to ensure the `sheets` reference is explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include how you set the `rng`, that's a vital bit of info to help troubleshoot.  But generally, this should work:

```
Sub t()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("sheet_1")

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C100")

For Each cel In rng.Cells
   cel.Value = "foo"
Next
End Sub
```